# how heavy is queue.push() and queue.pop() for cv:Mat with large resolution(say 1920x1080x3)

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, queue

I have two threads, one is spsc_queue.push(), one is spsc_queue.pop(), spsc_queue is an function of boost::lockfree. I will need to constantly push and pop a large cv::Mat (image with resolution 1920x1080x3), how time-consuming and resource load of push and pop in this case?

If it is too heavy, I may consider allocate memory from outside, only push and pop the pointer to the image memory. If it is not heavy, I will just push/pop cv::Mat directly.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not as light as a simple pointer, it does not directly contain image data as you might be worrying. It contains a pointer to the image data.

[Mat Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html)

Edit:
Given that you are pushing the Mat into the queue (not a pointer to a Mat), that Mat will be **copied and saved** in the queue. That being said, the reference to the smart pointer will be kept safely inside the queue. The image data will continue to live inside the memory until the Mat is popped from the queue, used, and destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, it's a pointer to Mat, then there is another issue, if the size of my queue is 50, then I need to keep all 50 original cv::Mat data outside at the worst case, since when I do pop, spsc_queue still needs to trace back to the original cv::Mat data through pointer, I can't delete original cv::Mat because I don't which one is already popped(unless deliberately calculate the number, this will complicate the procedure).

Comment: @Jack OpenCV handles that using smart pointer, you can just push your Mat into the queue without having to manually allocate/delete anything.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Even it is a smart pointer, unless another copy of data is stored somewhere, I can't delete my original copy, right? Here is some pseudo code.  I think below code is not correct, because in _push_thread.cpp, I reused img_frame,  when pop thread need it, the original copy of data has been overwritten many time, is my explanation reasonable?      
`code`_push_thread.cpp

cv::Mat img_frame;
while(1){}
 cap >> img_frame;
 boost_spsc_push(img_frame)
}

_pop_thread.cpp

cv::Mat pop_img_frame;
while(1){
 boost_spsc_push(&pop_img_frame)
}`code`

Comment: @Jack I suggest putting those code in the question. I guess you mean 'pop' for the second line? Anyway see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry, yes it's pop.  I will reorganize and put it in the question. code_push_thread.cpp cv::Mat img_frame; while(1){} cap >> img_frame; boost_spsc_push(img_frame) } _pop_thread.cpp cv::Mat pop_img_frame; while(1){ boost_spsc_pop(&pop_img_frame) }code